# Do I need double Authentication when working with provider-hosted apps?

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, windows-authentication, sharepoint-apps

**Problem:** I have to create another WebApplication outside of my SharePoint environment which uses Windows Authentication(NTLM) but this new WebApp will be called from SharePoint and I have to leave that domain changing "unknown" for the end user, however, users got to be authenticated in this new WebApp in order to see all the data. Therefore, I heard that SharePoint 2013 has this new Provider-Hosted App thing that I thought could work for me but somehow I still have to pass my credentials twice (#1 - when accessing SharePoint, #2 when redirected to the app) to get authenticated. Am I missing something or did I misunderstood how provider-hosted app really works?